# not able to CSS effect applied through jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am applying css to table rows through jquery as:

```
$('#01016').css("background-color", "green");
```

when is see in developer tool it shows style applied to element as:
[image]

But it is not affecting in actual html view:
[image]

Note: I am adding table rows through jquery dynamically using ajax and then applying css to given id based on provided in input box.

Comment: Try this: `$('#01016 td').css("background-color", "green");`

Comment: try `$('#01016 td')`

Comment: browser probabaly loads css after js, so you have no effect there

Comment: @AtillaArdaAçıkgöz CSS is loaded before JS, however the rules on the `td` may override those set on its parent `tr`

Comment: i am applying css after data creates table through js. It is based on user input once data shown in table format.

Comment: Check what styles are applied to the `td` within the row - it's likely that the styling on the `tr` is being overrriden

Comment: no style added to td

Comment: did you try with `!important` ?

Comment: yes if i tried $('#01016 td').css("background-color", "green !important"); but then nothing is applied in style. Is it invalid attribute value?

Comment: $('#01016 td').css("background-color", "green"); this answer worked for me.

Comment: i used some css framework which might override td style. Thanks for help.